# Keycloak: Update user password in AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, change-password, keycloak

I'm building an AngularJS application protected by Keycloak.
Each user should update his password within his user profile.

Calling the Keycloak API for password

> GET /auth/realms/{realm_name}/account/password

returns HTML content from Keycloak.
I would like to build my own form to update a user's password.

In the Keycloak documentation I found

> POST /auth/realms/{realm_name}/account/password

which requires the attributes

```
{
    'password' => user's current password
    'password-new' => new password
    'password-confirm' => new password again
    'stateChecker' => token from keycloak
}
```

Calling

> POST /auth/realms/{realm_name}/account/password

without the 'stateChecker' attribute causes an error. This attribute is needed.

So here are my questions:

- How do I get the value for `stateChecker` from keycloak for the logged in user (in Keycloak it's in a hidden input field)?
- Is there another possibility to change a user's password with a REST API call?

Thanks in advance.

**Note:**

Calling:

> POST /auth/realms/{realm_name}/account/password

with hard coded attributes and values

```
{
    'password': 'somepasswd',
    'password-new': 'someNEWpasswd',
    'password-confirm': 'someNEWpasswd',
    'stateChecker': '<token copied and pasted from keycloak>',
}
```

is working!

Comment: what version of keycloak are you using?

Answer (score 5):

My advice would be to overwrite the keycloak theme (check this out: http://docs.jboss.org/keycloak/docs/1.2.0.Beta1/userguide/html/themes.html).

You can extend and modify the existing forms to look like the rest of your application.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I ended up with an own implementation of a rest endpoint using keycloaks admin rest api.

Building an own theme could be a solution too, as Lisa stated.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach. Good to hear it's working.